# Python class for permutations

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to develop a program which will solve any permutation-based puzzle such as 15 puzzle or Rubik's cube, so there will be a follow-up question about class that actually solves puzzle. Here I ask about the class which is essential to this task: `Permutation` class.

```
class Permutation(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_letter_id(num):
        """
        Returns an identity permutation of first :num: number of 
        uppercase ASCII letters.
        """
        letters = string.ascii_uppercase[:num]

        return Permutation(tuple(zip(letters, letters)), "Id" + str(num))

    def __init__(self, perm, label=""):
        """
        :param perm: List of tuples of type (A, B), which shows that in given sequence of symbols
                        symbol A will be replaced by symbol B
        :param label: Label for better (or worse) representation. 
        """
        top_symbols = [p[0] for p in perm]
        bottom_symbols = [p[1] for p in perm]

        top_symbols = set(top_symbols)
        bottom_symbols = set(bottom_symbols)

        if top_symbols != bottom_symbols:
            raise Exception("Incorrect Permutation")

        self._perm = list(perm)
        self._perm.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
        self._label = str(label)

    @property
    def inverse(self):
        p = [(p[1], p[0]) for p in self._perm]
        p.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
        return Permutation(p, "Inverse({0})".format(self._label))

    @property
    def parity(self):
        return self._inversions % 2

    @property
    def symbols(self):
        return sorted([i for i, j in self._perm])

    @property
    def _inversions(self):
        res = 0
        top = [i for i, j in self._perm]
        bottom = [j for i, j in self._perm]
        for i in range(len(top)):
            for j in range(i, len(top)):
                if bottom[i] > bottom[j]:
                    res += 1
        return res

    def print_carrier(self):
        [print("{0} -> {1}".format(mutation[0], mutation[1])) for mutation in self._perm if mutation[0] != mutation[1]]

    def _find_symbol(self, symbol):
        for i in range(len(self._perm)):
            if self._perm[i][0] == symbol:
                return i
        raise Exception("Can't find given symbol in permutation.")

    def __call__(self, sequence):
        """
        Applies this permutation to the given sequence of symbols.
        For performance reasons this permutation assumed applicable to given sequence.
        """
        return tuple([self._perm[self._find_symbol(symbol)][1] for symbol in sequence])

    def __eq__(self, permutation):
        if type(permutation) != Permutation:
            return False
        condition1 = self.symbols == permutation.symbols
        condition2 = self.__call__(self.symbols) == permutation(self.symbols)
        return condition1 and condition2

    def __mul__(self, permutation):
        first = [mutation[0] for mutation in self._perm]
        second = self.__call__(permutation(first))
        return Permutation(tuple(zip(first, second)), str(self) + " * " + str(permutation))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._label
```

Performance should not be ignored too.

Comment: What are you asking, more specifically? Should the style of the code be reviewed, or the performance, or the logic (or all of them)?

Comment: @maxb, actually, I am interested in all of them (code style, performance and logic, though not all methods of this class need to be as fast as possible). The most questionable points are `__call__`, `__mul__` and `__eq__` methods and what data structure to use to store permutation itself.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     def __init__(self, perm, label=""):
>         """
>         :param perm: List of tuples of type (A, B), which shows that in given sequence of symbols
>                         symbol A will be replaced by symbol B
>         :param label: Label for better (or worse) representation. 
>         """
>         top_symbols = [p[0] for p in perm]
>         bottom_symbols = [p[1] for p in perm]
>
>         top_symbols = set(top_symbols)
>         bottom_symbols = set(bottom_symbols)
>
>         if top_symbols != bottom_symbols:
>             raise Exception("Incorrect Permutation")
> ```

That's an important check, but not a sufficient one. If I pass `[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]` then `top_symbols` and `bottom_symbols` will be the same set, but it's not a valid permutation.

---

> ```
>     @property
>     def inverse(self):
>         p = [(p[1], p[0]) for p in self._perm]
>         p.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
>         return Permutation(p, "Inverse({0})".format(self._label))
> ```

Why sort `p`? The constructor does that anyway.

---

> ```
>     @property
>     def symbols(self):
>         return sorted([i for i, j in self._perm])
> ```

Why `sorted`? The constructor does that already.

Also, why do some methods use `[something involving p[i] for p in self._perm]` and others `[something involving i and/or j for i, j in self._perm])`?

---

> ```
>     @property
>     def _inversions(self):
>         res = 0
>         top = [i for i, j in self._perm]
>         bottom = [j for i, j in self._perm]
>         for i in range(len(top)):
>             for j in range(i, len(top)):
>                 if bottom[i] > bottom[j]:
>                     res += 1
>         return res
> ```

This takes \$O(n^2)\$ time. There are \$O(n \lg n)\$ algorithms to do it, so since you say that performance is a concern you probably want to revisit this method.

---

> ```
>     def print_carrier(self):
>         [print("{0} -> {1}".format(mutation[0], mutation[1])) for mutation in self._perm if mutation[0] != mutation[1]]
> ```

The name is somewhat opaque: carrier?!

The implementation is also somewhat hacky. As far as I can tell without executing to double-check, this is using a list comprehension purely to iterate and produce side effects. Ugh.

---

> ```
>     def _find_symbol(self, symbol):
>         for i in range(len(self._perm)):
>             if self._perm[i][0] == symbol:
>                 return i
> ```

Whoa! If this method is used much at all, it's going to be a major performance hit. IMO you need to revisit the way the data is stored: to do this efficiently you want a `dict`.

Also: why return `i`? Under what circumstances would you call this method wanting anything other than `self._perm[i][1]`?

---

> ```
>     def __eq__(self, permutation):
>         if type(permutation) != Permutation:
>             return False
>         condition1 = self.symbols == permutation.symbols
>         condition2 = self.__call__(self.symbols) == permutation(self.symbols)
>         return condition1 and condition2
> ```

Why not just do an equality check on `_perm` and `permutation._perm`?

---

> ```
>     def __mul__(self, permutation):
>         first = [mutation[0] for mutation in self._perm]
>         second = self.__call__(permutation(first))
>         return Permutation(tuple(zip(first, second)), str(self) + " * " + str(permutation))
> ```

Firstly, DRY: `first` is `self.symbols`. Secondly, IMO a comprehension for `second` would be more clearly checkable against the definition of permutation composition. Thirdly, why `tuple(...)` in the call to the constructor? If `zip` works in `get_letter_id` it should work here too.